# Strategies for solving inequality sudoku?

Tags: python, math, sudoku

A twist on the classic sudoku solver that I've recently run into is the (rather crazy) [inequality sudoku](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_IbbWPS5nN5w/TTQ9HsR6irI/AAAAAAAAA1A/aB8HYIYumOY/s1600/greater.png), which is your classic sudoku puzzle with the added twist that there are inequality conditions added to each box.

Now, I've managed to scratch out a *regular* sudoku solver in Python (using a brute-force method), but I'm having trouble grasping what methods I would use to tackle this problem.  Am I overthinking it or is this much more complicated than a normal puzzle?

Comment: Is the theory behind this that they give you numbers that give multiple answers if the inequalities aren't there?

Comment: There's that, plus a case where they give you no numbers, just a board full of inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

This is just constraint solving.

If you have a sudoku board, then, for each cell (i, j) you have these constraints:

```
board[i, j] in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for each cell (a, j) where i != a: board[a, j] != board[i, j]
for each cell (i, b) where j != b: board[i, b] != board[i, j]
```

For particular cells, you already know what their value is. That's really just a different constraint:

```
board[c1, c2] == 7
```

And that's it. A brute-force checker can simply run through every possible way to fill in board cells (esp. paying attention to the first constraint), and check whether these constraints hold. If they all hold for that filling-in, then it can output the board. Otherwise, it keeps going.

If you now allow inequalities for specific positions, you can use that exact same brute-force algorithm. It's just a new check it has to do before saying the board is filled in correctly:

```
2 <= board[c3, c4] < 8
```

---

It's easy with brute-force, but it's also pretty easy with a logic programming language like Prolog, or a constraint programming library like [Numberjack](http://numberjack.ucc.ie/tutorial)

Here are the Numberjack versions of all the constraints above (in order of appearance):

```
board[i, j] = Variable(1, 9)
# ... need to define all the board before you execute the following:
for a in xrange(1, 10):
    model.add(board[a, j] != board[i, j])
    model.add(board[i, a] != board[i, j])
model.add(board[c1, c2] == 7)
    model.add(board[c3, c4] < 8)
model.add(board[c3, c4] >= 2)
```

This is not idiomatic for real use of a constraint solver. In real life, instead of specifying the !=s individually, you'd use an "All of these are different" constraint, AllDiff, and so on. But you get the idea.

Comment: Numberjack looks awesome! Thanks for introducing that to me :)

Comment: What would you say the best way to add all my constraints to the model is? I've got the board represented as a matrix: `board = Matrix(N*N, N*N, 1, N*N, 'cell_')` and a model `sudoku` with the constraints necessary to model a _regular_ sudoku game. Should I just add a whole bunch of inequality statements (i.e. `sudoku.add(board[0][0] > board[0][1])`, etc.) or is there a more efficient way I'm missing?

Comment: @Nathanial Truthfully I've never used Numberjack, I just googled for python constraint solving libraries and found it. Looks like it'd be something like `for row in board: sudoku.add(AllDiff(row))` and the same for columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably modify Peter Norvig's [solver](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html) to add these constraints.

Comment: EDIT: Replied to the wrong comment. Thanks for the tip, though—that solver is great.